# js card auto-detect on keyinput

Tags: javascript

I was given the following regex to build a card auto-detect prototype:

HWVisaElectronRegEx = @"^(4026|417500|4508|4844|4913|4917)[0-9]+";

HWMasterCardRegEx = @"^5[1-5][0-9]{14}";

I have built the following script:

```
    var opacity = 'greyOut';

    function greyOut(el){
        $('p').not(el).addClass(opacity);
    }

    function getCreditCardType(accountNumber){

        //start without knowing the credit card type
        var result = "unknown";

        if (/^4(?:[0-9]{12}|[0-9]{15})/.test(accountNumber))
        {
            result = "HWVisaRegEx";
            greyOut($('.HWVisaRegEx'));
        }

        else if (/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}/.test(accountNumber))
        {
            result = "mastercard";
            greyOut($('.mastercard'));
        }

        return result;

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var input = $('.card');

        input.keyup(function(){

            if(input.val() === ''){
                $('p').removeClass(opacity);
            }

            getCreditCardType(input.val());

            if(input.val() === ""){
              $('p').removeClass(opacity);
            }

        });


    });
```

with this being the html:

```
<label>Card Number</label><input type="number" class="card"/>
```

It detects the card only after you input the full card number, how could it work so that card is detected after only 1 or maximum 2 digits?

Comment: https://creditcardjs.com/

Comment: See http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=340 for a sample regex for visa and master.